# Ionic 2 RC1 - Remove Horizontal Rulers aka no-lines globally on ion-list item

Tags: ionic2

We all know

```
<ion-list no-lines>
```

But how to do this globally?

Answer (score 1):

You can set following in your scss file to take effect globally:

```
.list-md > .item-block:last-child, .list-md > .item-wrapper:last-child .item-block {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.list-md > .item-block:first-child, .list-md > .item-wrapper:first-child .item-block {
     border-top: 0px !important; 
}

.list-md .item-block .item-inner {
    border-bottom: 0px !important; 
}

.item-md.item-block .item-inner {
    border-bottom: 0px !important; 
}
```